# Microsoft Access database is not showing the Database Tools tab

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access Database where I am trying to restore the database links, but I do not see the database tools on the menu. How can I enable/show the tab again?

Comment: This problem and solution applies to all versions of MS Access, so I have removed the ms-access-2013 tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down the shift key when opening up database. This will open the database in development mode, and show any hidden menus.

Answer (score -1):

On the top tabs, click on External Data
The left section is Import&Link
The second icon is LinkedTableManager